# How can I see the full StackTrace in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, stack, trace

I run a class with Maven and I get the following StackTrace:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) @ ws-app-client ---
java.lang.RuntimeException: es.udc.ws.app.xml.ParsingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.udc.ws.app.client.service.rest.RestClientDealService.reserveDeal(RestClientDealService.java:166)
    at es.udc.ws.app.client.ui.DealServiceClient.main(DealServiceClient.java:190)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: es.udc.ws.app.xml.ParsingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.udc.ws.app.xml.XmlExceptionConversor.fromInstanceNotFoundExceptionXml(XmlExceptionConversor.java:106)
    at es.udc.ws.app.client.service.rest.RestClientDealService.validateStatusCode(RestClientDealService.java:283)
    at es.udc.ws.app.client.service.rest.RestClientDealService.reserveDeal(RestClientDealService.java:159)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.udc.ws.app.xml.XmlExceptionConversor.fromInstanceNotFoundExceptionXml(XmlExceptionConversor.java:101)
    ... 9 more
```

How can I see the 7 and 9 more errors?

I tried to execute the class with `-DtrimStackTrace=false` and `-e -X` switches, but It doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 7 and 9 omitted lines are in the first section.  What this is telling you is that the stack trace is identical with the previous one beyond that point.

In this case the actual cause is a NPE that was caught and wrapped (rethrown) in a `ParsingException`

Comment: I don't think so, I see ... 26 more